# How to align the textbox's for a editor for in mvc razor?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have razor EditorFor<> creating some textbox's for me but the alignment is terrible and i cant come right will straightening it up.

[image]

How would i align all the textboxs to start the same distance from the text?

View:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 50%;">

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Date)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Date)
    <br/>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.QuoteNumber)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.QuoteNumber)
    <br/>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ClaimNumber)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ClaimNumber)
    <br/>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MotorBodyRepairer)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MotorBodyRepairer)
    <br/>

</div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 50%;">

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.VehicleRegistration)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.VehicleRegistration)
    <br/>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.VehicleMake)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.VehicleMake)
    <br/>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.VehicleRange)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.VehicleRange)
    <br/>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.VehicleModel)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.VehicleModel)
    <br/>

</div>
```

Model:

```
namespace SpendDirect.WebUI.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class APNewQuoteViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Date")]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Quote Number")]
        public string QuoteNumber { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Claim Number")]
        public string ClaimNumber { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Motor Body Repairer")]
        public string MotorBodyRepairer { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Vehicle Registration")]
        public string VehicleRegistration { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Vehicle Make")]
        public string VehicleMake { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Vehicle Range")]
        public string VehicleRange { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Vehicle year Model")]
        public string VehicleModel { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply apply CSS

```
label
{
width:200px;
float:left;
text-align:left
}

input[type=text]
{
width:200px;
float:left;
}
```

In case, if you want to apply for few label, just add a class like `field` and write css selector like below and most recommended

```
label.field
{
//style goes
}
```

Then

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Date, new {@class="field"})
```

To apply `HTMLAttributes` for `EditorFor` you may need to send it as ***ViewData*** and use it in your Editor Template .

In MVC 5.1, you can use `htmlAttributes` parameter for EditorFor. [`Read the release notes`](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes#Bootstrap)

Answer (score 4):

You can use like this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.TITLEID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" , @style = "float: left;text-align: left;" })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
Dictionary<string, object> labelHtmlProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
labelHtmlProperties.Add("style", "width: 100px;"); //set the width as big you need...
```

In each `@Html.LabelFor` add the HTML properties:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Date, labelHtmlProperties )
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Date)
<br/>
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.QuoteNumber, labelHtmlProperties )
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.QuoteNumber)
<br/>
...
```

By using the same `Dictionary` containing the HTML properties, you ensure that all your labels are rendered using the same properties. Alternatively, you could add a class to the labels and add the width in the CSS. Or even better, set the styles for the labels in the context of your container `div`s.

Comment: Increasing the width did not do anything?

Comment: @Pomster, it depends on the style that you already have set on the labels. With how much did you increase the width?

Comment: Please use css class for a better control. You are using inline styles which is difficult for maintanance

Comment: As noted in my answer, that is one of the alternatives. However, I'd say this approach is pretty much easy to maintain, since you need to change the width in _only one_ place (i.e. the dictionary).